# Access number friendly name from Twilio studio

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

We are building an IVR and have multiple numbers per city for various campaigns. For example: Metro, Bus, Google, Facebook, Website and etc.

When a call is coming in, we're creating a lead on Salesforce with the number, but we are missing the campaign.

While having access to CallFrom number {{trigger.call.From}} and the CallTo number {{trigger.call.To}} we would like to access the number's friendly name as well.

This Friendly name of the number holds the campaign, is there a way to access it so it'll be sent out with the rest of the info?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you receive an incoming call from Twilio you are only sent the [request parameters in the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml#request-parameters) which do not include the friendly name of your number.

You could fetch that number by using a Twilio Function as part of your Studio flow. You'll need to pass the from number as an argument to the Function by setting it as a parameter in the widget settings, like this:

[image: Set a Function Parameter called "To" and fill it with <code>{{trigger.call.To}}</code>]

As you can see we are using the data `trigger.call.To` which is the incoming phone number.

Then, your Function would look something like this:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  const phoneNumber = event.To;
  const client = context.getTwilioClient();

  client.incomingPhoneNumbers.list(
    {
      phoneNumber: phoneNumber
    },
    (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        return callback(err);
      }
      const response = { FriendlyName: data.incomingPhoneNumbers[0].friendlyName };
      callback(null, response);
    }
  );
};
```

That would return the data to your flow and you would be able to access it later in the flow as `{{widgets.MY_WIDGET_NAME.parsed.FriendlyName}}`.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Answer (score 2):

Bit of an old post, just in case this can help someone...

First off, thank you Phil for showing me the way. I had to slightly modify your code to get it to work with the 3.x Twilio Client API, and I added the phoneNumber itself as a fallback value. This version is "known good" and working for me as of date of this post:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  const phoneNumber = event.To;
  const client = context.getTwilioClient();

  client.incomingPhoneNumbers.list(
    {
      phoneNumber: phoneNumber
    },
    (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        return callback(err);
      }
      console.log("data = " + data);
      var fName;
      if (data.length) {
          fName = data[0].friendlyName;
      }
      else {
          fName = phoneNumber;
      }
      const response = { FriendlyName: fName };
      callback(null, response);
    }
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. For any future readers this still works as of Feb 4 2020!